# Do XSS attacks only happen with GET and a POST request?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

I was watching a tutorial and the tutor put a XSS filter on a GET request only app.

My understanding of cross site scripting is using POST and GET. A “hacker” POSTs a script to the server and when your Web app makes a GET request it receives that script and the browser runs it when the script data loads onto the page.

This can effect all users viewing the page where the data (script) is recieved.

How would you be vulnerable if you had and only had a GET request web app?

Comment: It could be done over any http verb, over websockets, pretty much any communication that can be used to send data such that it is viewed by another user without being properly sanitized.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be under several misapprehensions here.

*Only POST requests can cause a server to store data* — **false**.

While the HTTP specification requires that GET requests are Safe and Idempotent, it is easy to write server-side code which violates this rule.

*Only GET requests can get data from a server* — **false**.

Most HTTP requests can have a response which includes a body for the client to render.

While it is often a good idea to use the Post-Redirect-Get pattern, this is not required, nor always the best approach. A POST request can have a response which is rendered in the browser.

*Data needs to be stored to cause an XSS vulnerability* — **false**

Many XSS attacks are of the Reflected form, where the input is directly echoed out in the response.

---

Let's take a naïve implement of a search engine like Google for example.

When you perform a search, the search term is displayed in an input element at the top of the page so you can modify it and make a new search.

```
<input name="q" value="<?php echo $_GET['q'];">
```

Now let's craft an XSS attack as a search string.

```
http://example.com/?q="><script>alert("XSS");</script>
```

That gets rendered on the page as:

```
<input name="q" value=""><script>alert("XSS");</script>">
```

… and vulnerability is obvious.

Comment: Ok I understood most of the your points about the http verbs and data storage isn't needed for a XSS attack. But on the last part you mentioned "Many XSS attacks are of the Refelcted form, where the input is directly echoed out in the response." Can you elaborate? How would that effect users besides yourself?

Comment: @Kevorkian – Have you never clicked a link that you didn't write yourself?

Comment: yes I have clicked on a link that I haven't written myself. What does that have to do with XSS? That would be the users fault if the user clicked on a link with some funky looking parameters.

Comment: @Kevorkian — Oh, before you click on any link, you examine the destination URL to make sure it doesn't look like an XSS attack? And you've configured your browser so it doesn't follow HTTP redirects so an innocent looking link can't redirect you? And you've disabled JavaScript so an innocent looking link can't land you on a page that programmatically submits a form or sets `location.href` to a new value?

Comment: What is has to do with XSS is that, as demonstrated in the answer, an XSS attack can be encoded into a link.

Comment: Why did you copy/paste my example into a comment? If it was an attempt to demonstrate that nothing happens, then nothing was supposed to. Hence "example.com". I didn't go out, find a website that was vulnerable to XSS attacks, and then out them here.

Comment: So every link can be edited so it performs a XSS attack? How can you protect against this?

Comment: I was trying the ask something with the example

Comment: No. Only sites which are vulnerable to XSS attacks can be targetted by XSS attacks. [There are no shortage of resources on how to defend against attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=defend%20against%20XSS)

Comment: NO? you just said that I can add a script inside a url? So your saying if google has protection against XSS I can't add a script to the url and have a user click it so it runs something malicious?

Comment: NVM I kinda get what you're saying

Comment: "So your saying if google has protection against XSS I can't add a script to the url and have a user click it so it runs something malicious?" — Yes. Hence "Only sites which are vulnerable to XSS attacks can be targetted by XSS attacks."